# Lazy load collections + GWT

Tags: hibernate, gwt, design-patterns, lazy-loading

I have DTO class with lazy load collections. Let say Author and Books. Client side is GWT.
So user have to select author, then he should see list of books. So I don't want to transfer authors books until author is selected. 
So flow is:

1. Load all authors whithout books to client
2. User select author
3. Load books of this author

I see 3 options:

- Don't copy books to author object first time when transfer to client side (i.e. create method like `getAllAuthorsWhitoutBooks()` and just not copy books there)
- Create special class `AuthorWhithoutBooks` and use it for first transfer
- Create `Set` subclass `NotLoadedSet` (and throw some exception at any action with it) and create `getAllAuthorsWhitoutBooks()` mehtod. So thansfered object will contain `NotLoadedSet` instances instead of real set of books.

Is there any paticular recipe for this case or common used approach?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to very simple with hibernate, ofcourse you will lazyload books collection in the.

```
class Author{
@OneToMany(lazy=true)
private List<Book> books;

}
```

When the user first asks for authors, obviously the books will not be loaded here.

When the user asks for books for an author with AuthorID = 1, (Send this to another method in the service layer say 'getAuthorWithBooks') then do the following in the service/manager

```
Author author = session.findById(AuthorID);
author.getBooks();
```

The above statement will load all the books of the author now. if the books are not loaded, 
try to use `Hibernate.initialize(author.getBooks())`

Comment: The question was not 'How make it work', but 'how make good desing'. What should return Author DTO object `getBooks()` method in GWT layer when it loaded first time (in authors list)? Did you count it's GWT?

Comment: So, you are sending the Entity object from the hibernate, directly to the client(Serializing)? if you are using custom DTO(another dto which is not Author entity) from the server to the client, you dont even have to deal with the getBooks() property because, you dont include it in the DO, even if you include, it will/should be null

Comment: bottom line is, create another Data objects/pojos to carry the data that is required by the client, if you send the domain objects to the client, you are implementing a tight coupled design which may have problem maintaining.

Comment: So, like my 'Create special class AuthorWhithoutBooks and use it for first transfer' option?

Comment: Yes. That is true. Note: This should apply to the whole system, all the data should be transferred to similar to special class that you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes. This is next problem I see. What if there some point where we want get author whit books at client side

Comment: Ok, I would leave the DTO Author as it is(with the book property in it), since you have the control as to what to send to the client, you need not set the book property on to the DTO when only authors are requested. Because, you know the context of the method that is called from the client: eg: in context getAuthros() method, you dont need to know about books, so create an array of Authors and set the properties that you need.

Comment: Yes, but lets imagine that after some time other developer will use this method for some reason and expect actual books.

Comment: Yes, I understand, you may use another service method getAuthorWithBooks() (which is not our initial service method getAuthors()) and again return authors list, this time include books  for each and every author. (obviously you document it somewhere for other programmer to understand what you are trying to do)

Comment: I've read some articles while. So my current idea is.
1)Keep entity class separate
2)Create AuthorFullDTO (getId, getName, getBooks) class
3)Create AuthorListDTO (getId, getName) class

Comment: Yes, that is true, even I follow that, I use this method, if I really want to trim down the number of class properties that I send across, say i have 30 in full DTO, i want to send only 10 properties, then it makes sense. Most of the time, I feel that it adds confusion to the developers and extra work to maintain two DTOs(maintain as in, map the DTO values into the Entity object, even if one column gets added, you have to update two DTOs now). It is now completely up to you as to how you want to go wit this.

Comment: @Zeus I posted another answer to complement yours. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid sending useless data back and forth and keep queries as simple and fast as possible.

1° Use named queries or criteria projections to get only the required (author withoud books) data.

2° Get a set of Books (without author) instead of AuthorWithBooks since you already have the author.

3° Use converters to map a subset of the entity fields (only the required one, converted when needed) and decouple the entities from the client code.

After reading the above answer & comments, I'll try to give some further advice & tricks.

Zeus advice to decouple entities and shared object is correct.

This decoupling is a pain for data oriented services. You may want to have a look at [RequestFactory](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) if you are writing such a service. In most cases I stick to decoupling the shared objects and the entities by writing converters. I often don't want to map the full entity to a shared object "as-is", and might want to convert some of the fields to make the shared object easier to use in the client code.

Note You can also use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) for the conversion but I heard it's a bit slow.

@xander27 beware of

> "lets imagine that after some time other developer will use this
>   method for some reason and expect ..."

@zeus your solution is right but I don't agree with creating objects that are null 'by convention'

> "if you include [books], it will/should be null"

Maybe you saw this as implicit but I'll still say it. If you want to have an Author and an AuthorWithBook class, use inheritance and make AuthorWithBooks extends Author. It's better to use inheritance than null. If programmers need other data they should extend the base class (or even better refactor the hierarchy according to the system needs and avoid it being bloated). Keep thinking OO.

With Hibernate, I often use criteria projections to load only a part of the fields of an entity, instead of `@OneToMany(lazy=true)`. This makes my queries faster, while I can use a simple getById for the "big" query when all the entity tree is loaded. Named queries will also work but I like criterias.

Hope this helps.